# understanding plot function

Tags: pine-script

eg. https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_plot

New to Pine, not new to programming.

When it says the first parameter is a data series, such as hl2 or ema, is this series the values of all the time periods on the visible chart?  In other words where does this series come from?
So if you look at the ema function, its parameter is a source...which is what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That parameter is a variable name which can be a built-in like `close` or `hl2`, or one you've created yourself. The variable can represent a series, which means there is one value for it for every bar in the dataset. The values of time series can change for each bar. Note that the parameter does not *have* to be a series; it can be a literal, like in:

```
plot(0)
```

The parameter can also be an expression, as in:

```
plot(abs(close - open))
```

It can even be a conditional expression, as in:

```
plot(close > open ? high : low)
```

[This](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Quickstart_guide.html#series) is the usrman on series.

Comment: Maybe my real question is what series of data is returned by a function like close or hl2?  Is it the values for each bar of data on the "displayed" time period?  In other words, what is the data returned.  So based on what youve said a function like close will represent a dataset of the closing prices of each bar over the time period displayed on the chart?  Thanks for the link, ive been looking for a good online manual.  I was starting with the wiki page but it was leaving me scratching my head a bit.

Comment: `close` is a variable—not a function—of type *float* and of form *series* and yes, as you say, for historical bars its value is the closing price of the symbol on the chart. In the realtime bar, its value is the current price. `close` is the value of the series for the current bar; `close[1]` the value for the preceding bar.